# Modify a Runnable class attribute across the time

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Is it possible to modify across the time an attribute from a class implementing the Runnable interface?

I have created a game loop in a GamePanel class implementing the Runnable interface.
However, as I expected, it is impossible to modify a boolean attribute like this:

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean _isPaused;
    public synchronized void setPause(boolean b) {
        _isPaused = b;
    }

    public synchronized boolean getPause() {
        return _isPaused;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!_isPaused)
            draw();
   }

   public void draw()
   {
       if (_isPaused)
            drawPauseScreen();
        else
            drawGameScreen();
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity, I have a listener attached to a simple button:

```
private View.OnClickListener buttonPauseListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      _gamePanel.setPause(!_gamePanel.getPause());
  }

};
```

When I click on the pause button, the boolean is changed, but clicking on it a second will not change the boolean anymore.

Comment: You are always setting the _isPaused value, in the onClick you should not be doing this? _gamePanel.setPause(!_gamePanel.getPause());

Comment: I edited the code, it was a pasting mistake.
I have :
_gamePanel.setPause(!_gamePanel.getPause());
and this is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can change the boolean as you're doing, but it's in my mind not following best practices.

You current problem is that you exit the while loop, thus the runnable is no longer running, as soon as you change the boolean to true so it's not drawing anymore.

Edit:
I would recommend using an AtomicBoolean instead to make the code clearer.

Comment: I think I may be tired to post such a dumb mistake. Thank you

Comment: Happens to us all :)

Maybe you have them and are just not including them, but a tip would be to have some logging. For example when you:
1) Entering runnable
2) Exiting runnable